# update-alternatives throws error in CDH4 installation

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am installing CDH4 on my ubuntu 12.04 system. While I am pointing towards my hadoop_conf using update-alternative it throws an error. I have searched everywhere but didn't get a solution to this problem.

command used :-
               sudo update-alternatives --install /etc/hadoop/conf hadoop-conf    /etc/hadoop/conf.my_cluster 50

```
           sudo update-alternatives --set hadoop-conf /etc/hadoop/conf.my_cluster
```

This gives an error...

update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/hadoop/conf.my_cluster': Too many levels of symbolic links

Please help. I am trying to set up a 3 node cluster on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Answer (score 0):

```
  sudo update-alternatives --set hadoop-conf $(readlink -f /etc/hadoop/conf.my_cluster)
```

Comment: This command shows me the update-alternative help option. There is something wrong with the command. Please help...